# What is wrong with this code? .Find , VBA

Tags: excel, vba, find

I have two subs, First sub "Find" finds all the values in column G , range (G1:G10) , there i have three values so it loops 3 times and gives me the value.

Now i am calling a second sub "Find2" to find that value in column A, range (A1:A10). the problem is it runs only once.. it is not looping three times to get 3 values. Any idea ?. why it is not working.

```
Sub Find()

Set shtSheet1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
With shtSheet1.Range("G1:G10")
    Set V = .find("*", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not V Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddress = V.Address

        Do
        X = V
        Call Find2
        Set V = .FindNext(V)

        Loop While Not V Is Nothing And V.Address <> FirstAddress

    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Second sub

```
Public Sub Find2()

Set shtSheet1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set shtSheet2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

    With shtSheet1.Range("A1:A10")
        Set C = .find(X, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not C Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox X
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You  need to post more code.  Where is **X** Dim'ed??

Comment: on top of the sheet as a global variable..

Comment: Is **X** a Range or a value??

Comment: As a string....because it can be anything..number ..or text

Comment: O.K.....so each time Find2() gets called, its searching always starts to the top rather than at the point it found the previous X??

Comment: I don't understand your question exactly. Sub1 finds the first value in the middle or 2nd not the first value. then that value passed to sub2 there it shows the msgbox with the first string and then the loop stops.

Answer (score 1):

I think that using .Find() in the subroutine is interfering with the .FindNext() in the main routine.

Comment: Rather than using .Find() in the subroutine, loop down the cells in a **For** loop to search for **X**

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Gary, there's some interference going on.  Instead of using Find() in your subroutine, see if this will work for you.

```
Public Sub Find2()
    Dim shtSheet1 As Worksheet
    Dim C As Range

    Set shtSheet1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set C = shtSheet1.Range("A1:A10")

    If Not IsError(Application.Match(X, C, 0)) Then
        MsgBox X
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
private Function Find2()
end function
```

insted of sub